# Network switch simultaneous client-to-client speeds?

Tags: switch, speed

If I have a 24-port gigabit switch with no uplink, and the odd-numbered downlink clients are transferring data to the even-numbered downlink clients, will I theoretically have (12 x 1 gigabit) communication channels, or (1 gigabit / 12) communication between each pair?

What features would a switch need to have to achieve the 12x1 performance if it doesn't already do so?

---

Update: From this closed [ServerFault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/505125/calculating-backplane-capacity-of-a-switch) I've learned that to calculate the required backplane capacity I would need to calculate 24*1 Gbs or 24 GBs capacity. For theoretical maximum, it would be 24*2 Gbs = 48 Gbs. If I'm searching for a switch, what marketing terms should I look for to avoid purchasing an under-capacity switch?

---

Update: The positive marketing terms I've found are "non-blocking", "no output contention", "100% throughput", and "wire speed" (plus checking the backplane capacity).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, modern switches are "non-blocking", ie. they can forward any bandwidth not exceeding the capacity of the output port(s). (With the possible exception of large, chassis switches with very high-speed ports.)

In your example, you should be able to run the full port speed across any pairs you want simultaneously - 12x 1 Gbit/s in duplex. Check the switch specifications for details. This is usually listed as "48 Gbit/s" (counting each ingress and egress bit and running in each direction).

Comment: What marketing terms should I look for to find such a switch and avoid purchasing one with a lower backplane capacity? Any terms to avoid? e.g. "fast ethernet" = "very slow ethernet" today

Comment: "Fast Ethernet" is the second generation with 100 Mbit/s - rather slow today, but still the basic standard. "Non-blocking" or "wire-speed" is what you want. And make sure it's got the right number of Gbit ports.

Answer (score 1):

The answer will be different for every model of switch.  Some switches are designed to process every port at wire speed, but others will oversubscribe the backplane to save money.

Comment: I didn’t know that. What terminology should I look for in the switch that does the 12x1?

Comment: You might see the term "non-blocking."  Also, the backplane speed has to be higher that the sum of all the port speeds.